# Create a grid with different sized boxes

Tags: html, css

How do I make a grid with 3 columns with div boxes in each column? The inner div boxes can have different heights. The content will be pulled from a database.

Comment: try http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no CSS rules overriding default behavior, the height of a div will grow or shrink depending on its content by default. You could create 3 columns by making 3 container divs and floating them to be side by side. Inside each container could be the dynamically created divs.

Here is an example.

```css
html, body{ height:100%; width:80%; }

.container{ 
    padding:1%;
    padding-right:2%;
    padding-left:2%;
    width:25%;
    margin-right:1%;
    background-color:#eee; 
    float:left;
}

.dynamic{
    background-color:#ddd;
    padding:4%;
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "dynamic">
        content
    </div>
    <div class = "dynamic">
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content
    </div>
    <div class = "dynamic">
        content<br>
        content
    </div>
    <div class = "dynamic">
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
    </div>
        <div class = "dynamic">
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "container">
    <div class = "dynamic">
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
    </div>
    <div class = "dynamic">
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
    </div>
    <div class = "dynamic">
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "container">
    <div class = "dynamic">
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
        content<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that each inner div's height grows directly with its content. If you wanted your container divs to be a fixed height, just set the value in CSS.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really think that way. I thought it was way more difficult. But it is quite easy.

Comment: No problem,  In response to @Neil McGuigan you don't absolutely *need* frameworks like bootstrap to pull this off, although every developer *should* learn frameworks like bootstrap as it will probably make your life a lot easier! :)